# Jquery not getting img from database

Tags: c#, jquery, html

So I'm updating this webpage with a new layout..  and now I can't seem to get an image from the database.

Old Code:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < inspirationItems.length; i++) 
{
    var item = inspirationItems[i];
    $("#participantContainer").append(
            "<div class='inspirationItemContainer sharkbox top'>" +
            "<img style='margin-left: 3px;' class='inspirationItem imagebox' interestId='" + item.InterestId + "' participantId='" + item.ParticipantId + "' src='/Infrastructure/ServeImage.aspx?Size=150&MemberId=" + item.MemberId + "&ImageId=" + item.ImageId + "'><br>" +
            "<div class='inspirationItem' style='width: 90px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden' interestId='" + item.InterestId + "' participantId='" + item.ParticipantId + "'>" + item.Name + "</div>" +
            "<div style='position:absolute; right: 3px; bottom: 3px;'><img style='width: 40px; height: 40px' src='/images/icons/" + item.Interest + ".png'></div>" +
            "</div>");
}
```

New Code:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < inspirationItems.length; i++) {

 var item = inspirationItems[i];
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(item.InterestDetails);
 $("#participantContainer").append(
     "<div class=' inspirationItemContainer sharkbox col-sm-6 col-md-3'> " +
      //  "<div img style='margin-left: 3px;' class='thumbnail inspirationItem imagebox' interestId='" + item.InterestId + "' participantId='" + item.ParticipantId + "' src='/Infrastructure/ServeImage.aspx?Size=150&MemberId=" + item.MemberId + "&ImageId=" + item.ImageId + "'><br>"<

      "<div class='thumbnail inspirationItem' interestId='" + item.InterestId + "' participantId='" + item.ParticipantId + "'> <img class=' imagebox'  src='/Infrastructure/ServeImage.aspx?Size=150&MemberId=" + item.MemberId + "&ImageId=" + item.ImageId + "'  />   " +

      "<div class='inspirationItem caption'  interestId='" + item.InterestId + "' participantId='" + item.ParticipantId + "'>" +
                "<h3>" + item.Name + " </h3>" +
       //"<p> " + obj.PartOfTown + obj.Level + "</p>" + "</div></div></div>"
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: img tag doesn't require '/' at the end though.

Comment: What is the entire url? Can you get to the img via address

Comment: im not sure what u mean eugenekgn..